# jquery ui dialog caching on form load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-ui-dialog

With ASP.NET MVC3 (Razor) I have a simple page that loads a jQuery UI dialog.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>yo</h2>
<div id="fileUpload">
</div>
<button id="button2">
    Upload file
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button2').click(function () {
            $fileUpload = $('#fileUpload');
            $fileUpload.dialog({
                minWidth: 500,
                minHeight: 100,
                title: 'Upload File(s)',
                autoOpen: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Upload': function () {
                        $('form').submit();
                    },
                    'Cancel': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load('@Url.Action(MVC.FileUpload.FileUpload())');
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                    //$(this).remove();
                },
                dialogClass: 'no-close',
                closeText: '',
                modal: true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Notice on open() the form makes a call to a controller method.  It returns a PartialView and looks like this...

> public virtual ActionResult FileUpload()        {           return new
>   PartialViewResult();      }

The problem I am having is IE is caching the call to the partial view.  If I update the partial view then it does not load until I clear the browser cache.

I have tried the 'destroy' method on close() as well as .remove().  Neither have an effect.  I have also confirmed open() is called each time #button2 is clicked.

Any ideas on how to keep the dialog contents from getting cached?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this to your global js code to prevent IE from ever caching ajax request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  All are correct, but I marked this one as the answer I need b/c it solves the issue on a global level.

Comment: FYI From the Docs: "If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL." See this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

You could replace:

```
 $(this).load('@Url.Action(MVC.FileUpload.FileUpload())');
```

with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action(MVC.FileUpload.FileUpload())',
    cache: false,
    context: this,
    success: function(result) {
        $(this).html(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute
[NoCache] 
To your controller action to fix this issue. This happens only in IE

Comment: Actually I've seen this in certain mobile browsers and under certain conditions in other desktop browsers as well. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Append a random parameter, or timestamp, to the URL to load. For example:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
$(this).load('@Url.Action(MVC.FileUpload.FileUpload())'+'&t='+timestamp);
```